# create typescript interface with readonly fields similar to one without readonly fields

Tags: typescript, interface

I have two interfaces:

```
Interface readwrite {
  f1: string;
  f2: boolean;
}

Interface readonlyint {
  readonly f1: string;
  readonly f2: boolean;
}
```

Sometimes I want that the fields cannot be changed, so I created the readonlyint interface. I there a possibility to derive readonlyint from readwrite? I don't want to copy all fields, the field-list can be much longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Readonly<T>` type, which you can use. It is doing the same.

```
interface ReadWrite {
   f1: string;
   f2: boolean;
}

type ReadonlyReadWrite = Readonly<ReadWrite>;
```

The shape of the `ReadonlyReadWrite` will be

```
interface ReadonlyReadWrite {
   readonly f1: string;
   readonly f2: boolean;
}
```